# DbUpdateConcurrencyException in Outbox MassTransit

Tags: entity-framework, rabbitmq, masstransit, outbox-pattern

We are currently using MassTransit and MassTransit embedded Outbox with generally successful results in our development and testing environments. However, when we transition to the live environment, we encounter some unusual behavior. Specifically, as the volume of messages increases, we start receiving a significant number of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` errors in the live environment.

MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCore:  8.0.16

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer : 7.0.8,

net7.0

```
MT-Fault-Message:   The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetAsync(Int32 startCommandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<<Send>g__Execute|0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory.cs:line 76
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<<Send>g__Execute|0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory.cs:line 104
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<<Send>g__Execute|0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory.cs:line 104
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, OutboxConsumeOptions options, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration/EntityFrameworkOutboxContextFactory.cs:line 113
at MassTransit.Middleware.OutboxConsumeFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/OutboxConsumeFilter.cs:line 41
at MassTransit.Middleware.OutboxConsumeFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/OutboxConsumeFilter.cs:line 41
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.Attempt(TContext context, RetryContext`1 retryContext, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 158
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.Attempt(TContext context, RetryContext`1 retryContext, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 238
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 128
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 47
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 118
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 47
at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 118
```

To address this issue, I attempted to handle the exception by configuring our message retry mechanism as follows:

```cs
endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
{
    r.Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>();
    r.None();
});

endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
{
    r.Ignore<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>();
    r.Intervals(
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10),
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    );
});
```

Unfortunately, even with this setup, there are instances where `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` errors still end up in the error queue. What's particularly puzzling is that when these exceptions occur in other queues that are not explicitly configured to ignore them, they also affect the queue that is supposed to ignore them.

Additionally, I attempted to resolve the issue by setting the service lifetime of the `DbContext` to Transient, but this change did not produce the desired results.

We are currently seeking assistance and advice on how to address this issue and ensure the reliable operation of our application in the live environment.

Comment: [Support](https://masstransit.io/support) is available.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thank you for sharing the link. My question is there any load and stress test proof for the MT outbox?

Comment: There is a [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox) you can put whatever load you want on it. I haven't seen any issues with concurrency under load that weren't due to the database, and sufficient retry recovers just fine. Kind of the point of using the outbox.

Comment: I have previously encountered this sample and used it as a guide to implement the outbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** retry `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, and yet, you are going to great lengths to ensure you do *not* retry them. Your retry configuration is wrong.

```cs
endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
{
    r.Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>();
    r.Intervals(
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10),
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    );
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between handling and not handling a DbUpdateConcurrencyException? By default, my retry policy makes three attempts. What would occur if I exclude the handle command? I assume the outcome would be identical. My issue is that I have numerous messages in the error queue that do not involve any business problems, and the application can consume them if there is no DbUpdateConcurrencyException.

Comment: Without `Handle<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>()` all exception types would be retried. If you want all exceptions retried, simply remove it.